# PHP - Creating a table failure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web, html-table

So, I am trying to create a table with PHP on my server, but it is failing to do so even though it is connecting to my server correctly. Here is my code:

```
// alphacrmTableCreate.php | Ryan Castle | 09/04/2014 - This script CREATEs sables     tCompany and tPerson in the database 'alphacrm'

{ // Connect and test mySQL and specific DB

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$databaseName = "alphacrm";

$dbConnected = @mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
$dbSelected = @mysql_select_db($databaseName, $dbConnected);

$dbSuccess = true;
if ($dbConnected) {
    if (!$dbSelected) {
        echo "DB connection FAILED<br><br>";
        $dbSuccess = false;
    } else {
        echo "DB connection SUCCESSFUL<br><br>";
        $dbSuccess = true;
    }
} else
    echo "mySQL connection FAILED<br><br>";
    $dbSuccess = false;
}

if ($dbSuccess) {
        //Table script here
    echo "Table created";
} else {
    echo "Table creation has failed";
}
```

I have tried to find an error in the script, and it looks as if it is located around the `if ($dbSuccess) {` line. It works if I put `if (!$dbSuccess) {` but that would not be helpful as it doesn't fix my problem. Any help will be appreciated.
~Ryan

Comment: which PHP version are you using? It is possible msyql_* doesn't work.

Comment: I don't use a downloaded version of PHP, I think it just connects to the most recent version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a  {

```
 else
    echo "mySQL connection FAILED<br><br>";
    $dbSuccess = false;
}
```

Also you will have to close the  if statement. Here is the full block corrected

```
if ($dbConnected) {
    if (!$dbSelected) {
        echo "DB connection FAILED<br><br>";
        $dbSuccess = false;
    } else {
        echo "DB connection SUCCESSFUL<br><br>";
        $dbSuccess = true;
    }
} else {
    echo "mySQL connection FAILED<br><br>";
    $dbSuccess = false;
}

}
```

Comment: After adding this, I receive this from the server:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbWIP\alphacrmTableCreate.php on line 70

 - This corresponds to the "?>" at the end of the file.

Comment: at the end of if ($dbConnected) { add the }, right after closing the else statement

Comment: Thanks for the help Ovidiu B, I will have to pay closer attention to my braces next time I debug.

Comment: Checking the brackets should be the first debug you are doing when you have errors ;)